# Paypal MPL IOS SDK "The system is currently unavailable. Please try again later"

Tags: android, ios, paypal

I have had MPL integrated into an IOS for some time, it has been working perfectly for months, not some users are getting a paypal error saying "The system is currently unavailable. Please try again later".

Any one know why this is happening.

screenshot of error is here
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5596699/image.png

thanks!

Comment: same problem on Android. I can't simply login.

Comment: Really blocking issue, we got the same problem since 2 days, our customers can't pay anymore !!

Comment: I logged a support ticket with Paypal about 5 days ago, no reply..

Comment: What is the ticket number? I can look it up. I'm not familiar with the error but I can look it up. 

Are you, user2529852, using iOS6-7 with the old MPL?

Comment: Did you find the solution? Since I'm also facing the same problem in android even though I have shifted to Live production :/ .. Please Advise

Answer (score 1):

I have received the following response from PayPal concerning this issue:

Which MPL are you using? The certificates expired in the older MPL which would explain the error message being thrown suddenly. If you're not currently using it, please update to the latest MPL version via the below link.

https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/tree/gh-pages/MPL

Comment: I was using MPL 1.5.5.44 when it stopped working. Switched to 1.5.5.45 (the latest) but now PayPal.getCheckoutButton explodes with null pointer exception at com.paypal.android.a.e.a

Comment: Update: null pointer exception is thrown when the largest button is used (PayPal.BUTTON_294x45)