# PayPal Adaptive Payments login fails

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

My website uses the PayPal Adaptive Payments API with the Embedded Payments flow and simple payments.  On my checkout page I execute a Pay API call, receive successful response, then call SetPaymentOptions and again get successful response.  The customer then reviews the order form and upon confirmation of the order is redirected to https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay in the PPDGFrame iFrame with expType set to "light" and the paykey received from the Pay API call.

I have successfully tested it in a sandbox and rolled it out to production.  The application worked great for a day or two and then stopped working, with buyers now receiving a "Please try again later" error when trying to login.  I am still getting successful responses on both the Pay and the SetPaymentOptions API calls and the customer is successfully redirected to the PayPal login screen.  The customer enters the login credentials, clicks the Login button and a couple seconds later gets the "Please try again later" message.

Now here are some really odd behaviours if I've ever seen odd... This problem first appeared about 4 days ago.  Since PayPal advised me that it will take them "several weeks" to get back to me, I have tried the checkout again two days ago and experienced the same problem.  I have then tried a guest checkout and it worked!  Next I tried a regular user checkout and it was successful as well so I thought to myself that the problem has somehow resolved itself.

Yesterday morning I tried the checkout again, and got the same problem as before.  Again I tried to checkout as guest, which again was successful, and then immediately after I have tried regular checkout and again this time I was able to login successfully.

Today the flow is broken again.  What gives?  Nothing is changing on my site.  Why does it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't, and how is it that a guest checkout seems to be able to temporarily resolve the issue?

Comment: This appears to be the same issue as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354230/paypal-mpl-ios-sdk-the-system-is-currently-unavailable-please-try-again-later.  The problem I have described has also first appeared on June 27 although the message I get is slightly different (in my case it only says "Please try again later) - could be due to the fact that I'm running on a Windows OS and not a mobile device.

Comment: Bumping this as I'm getting the same error.
Paypal MTS is not being very helpful, at the rate of 1 "wrong" answer a day it's tough keeping positive.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved with no action on my part and no change to the website or application code.  After a couple weeks of the API simply not working, it started working intermittently with gradually improving success rate while my support ticket with PayPal was sitting in a "Waiting" status.  I was told that the "engineering team" is waiting for a server code roll-out.  The intermittent nature of the problem and a gradually improving situation suggests that PayPal was rolling out a fix to their servers in a staged approach and outcome of the API operation depended on which server the PayPal load balancer happened to send the request to.  After about a week of that, the problem was resolved completely.  PayPal of course maintains that they have not made any server changes.